# How to view folder permission in windows using command line for particular user?

Tags: windows, permissions

I want to do this using command prompt, sometimes we need to check users permission, so can you please suggest how to view permission using command line in windows, Thanks.

[image]

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html ?

Answer (score 25):

You can use the `icacls` command in cmd. Like this:

```
icacls folder/file name
```

eg:

```
>>> C:\Users\Username> icacls Desktop

Desktop NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
ComputerName\Username:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
```

---

While in powershell you can use the command `Get-Acl`

eg:

```
PS C:\Users\Username> Get-Acl


    Directory: C:\Users


Path       Owner               Access
----       -----               ------
Username   NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl...
```

Or to get the info of all files and folder inside that directory:

```
PS C:\Users\Username> Dir | Get-Acl


    Directory: C:\Users\Username


Path                     Owner                  Access
----                     -----                  ------
.anaconda                Owner Name             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl...
.android                 Owner Name             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl...
.atom                    Owner Name             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl...
.aws                     Owner Name             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl...
.conda                   Owner Name             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl...
.config                  Owner Name             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl...
.DataGrip2018.2          Owner Name             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl...
.dotnet                  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl...
.elasticbeanstalk        Owner Name             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl...
.idlerc                  Owner Name             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl...
.ipython                 Owner Name             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl...
.keras                   Owner Name             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl...
... List goes on ....
```